# How get list of IDs from two table and pass in third table in my sql

Tags: jquery, mysql

i want get list of IDs from two table and have to pass in third tables where condition....i have write a query but its not working

```
SELECT u.ID,u.FIRST_NAME
FROM users u 
WHERE u.ID IN(
    SELECT cs.USER_ID 
    FROM comments cs 
    WHERE cs.NEWS_ID=839 
    GROUP BY cs.USER_ID) 
AND u.ID IN(
    SELECT nu.USER_ID 
    FROM news_user nu 
    WHERE nu.NEWS_ID=839 
    GROUP BY nu.USER_ID)
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have aggregate function so remove the group by evntually use distinct

```
SELECT  u.ID,u.FIRST_NAME FROM users u 
WHERE   u.ID IN (
          SELECT distinct cs.USER_ID FROM comments cs WHERE cs.NEWS_ID=839 ) 
    AND u.ID IN(SELECT distinct nu.USER_ID FROM news_user nu WHERE nu.NEWS_ID=839 );
```

in this way  you get the  id common to the two in clause ..